Installing Expo Google Auth problems
I'm fairly new to react native so please bear with me-
I am unable to install expo google auth as I get this error and I'm unsure what it means
typepm i expo-google-auth
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: react-dom@18.3.1
npm error Found: react@18.2.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @react-native-community/hooks@2.8.1
npm error   node_modules/@react-native-community/hooks
npm error     @react-native-community/hooks@"^2.8.1" from tailwind-rn@4.2.0
npm error     node_modules/tailwind-rn
npm error       tailwind-rn@"^4.2.0" from the root project
npm error   peer react@"*" from @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@12.2.1
npm error   node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin
npm error     @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@"^12.2.1" from the root project
npm error   13 more (@react-native/virtualized-lists, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.3.1" from react-dom@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react-dom
npm error   peerOptional react-dom@"*" from @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@12.2.1
npm error   node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin
npm error     @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@"^12.2.1" from the root project
npm error   peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.19.12
npm error   node_modules/react-native-web
npm error     react-native-web@"~0.19.10" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@"^18.3.1" from react-dom@18.3.1
npm error   node_modules/react-dom
npm error     peerOptional react-dom@"*" from @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@12.2.1
npm error     node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin
npm error       @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@"^12.2.1" from the root project
npm error     peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.19.12
npm error     node_modules/react-native-web
npm error       react-native-web@"~0.19.10" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /Users/USER/.npm/_logs/2024-06-19T01_43_27_344Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/USER/.npm/_logs/2024-06-19T01_43_27_344Z-debug-0.log here

So I tried to do the installation with a --force flag instead and it downloaded. However my app is unable to render when I do this.
Could not install, when --force was used app is unable to render.

Try installing the package with npx expo install expo-google-auth
